# Smali syntax for String

Tags: syntax, smali

Is there a website to learn smali syntax ?

I don't understand anything, I can't even affect a String !

```
Original code :

sget-object v1, Landroid/os/Build;->MANUFACTURER:Ljava/lang/String;

I want to put "samsung" in v1

sget-object v1, "samsung":Ljava/lang/String; -> error
sget-object v1, "samsung"; -> error
v1 = "samsung"; -> error
```

Comment: Here's an advice: write code in Java, build and then decompile to smali + check the produced smali code.

Comment: Usually my approach is as Alex proposed, but in this case it is even more simple: get [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) open up an APK and open a class in the tree view, then switch to SMALI tab. As most classes have at least one code line where a string is used you will find with a high chance the correct code. And if you by chance selected a class that does not conatain a string switch to the next class.

Answer (score 0):

The DEX command `sget-object` is for loading a value from a static field of a class:

> Perform the identified object static field operation with the identified static field, loading or storing into the value register. <sup>[1](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/dalvik-bytecode?hl=en)</sup>

If you want to load a string constant into a register you can simply write

```
const-string v1, "samsung"
```